# Using HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection to connect to an https?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

What are the differences if I try to connect to an "https" using `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection`?

I was able to connect to "https" using both `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection` so I am confused. I thought I can only establish a connection to an "https" if I used `HttpsURLConnection?`

Below are some of my questions:

- If I was able to open a connection to an "https" using HttpURLConnection, is my connection still in "https" or does it become "http"?
- How about the validating of certificates? Since I didn't any `SSLSocketFactory` and `HostnameVerifier` on my `HttpURLConnection` while connecting to an "https", what `SSLSocketFactory` and `HostnameVerifier` am I using?
- Does it mean that I am trusting everything regardless if the certificate is trusted or not?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. HTTPS connection being used.
2. Default Behaviors
3. Not sure but read below.

I just wrote some code as a test (see all the way below). What ends up happening is the *URL.openConnection()* call will give you back a *libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl* class.

This is an implementation of HttpsURLConnection but HttpsURLConnection inherits from HttpURLConnection. So you're seeing polymorphism at work.

Looking further into the debugger it appears that the class is using the default factory methods.

hostnameVerifier = [javax.net.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getDefaultHostnameVerifier%28%29)

sslSocketFactory = [org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getDefaultSSLSocketFactory%28%29)

**Based on this it looks like the default behaviors are being used. I don't know if that means if you're trusting everything but you are definitely establishing an HTTPS connection.**

The documentation kinda hints at the connection will auto-trust CAs that are well known but not self-signed. (see below) I did not test this but they have example code on [how to accomplish that here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html).

> If an application wants to trust Certificate Authority (CA)
>   certificates that are not part of the system, it should specify its
>   own X509TrustManager via a SSLSocketFactory set on the
>   HttpsURLConnection.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try {
        URL test = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) test.openConnection();
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        String value = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        Log.w("GOOGLE", value);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Test", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

};

Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried connecting to different https websites using your code. The default behavior of the SSLSocketFactory is to accept only certicates signed by CAs. I received a sun.security.validator.ValidatorException when I tried connecting to a website whose certificate is self-signed. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I see, So if you know the server only accepts HTTPS URI's, you can safely use `HttpURLConnection` to do your requests?